# Как вывести динамический сайдбар в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Делаю тему для Wordpress с нуля и возникла проблема - не получается вывести динамический сайдбар, помогите решить проблему, пожалуйста.

```
<div id="main-sidebar-wraper">
            <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-devhelper' ) ) : ?>
            <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
            <aside>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </aside>
            <aside>
                <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=12'); ?>
            </aside>
        </div>
```

Статическое содержимое выводится, а динамическое, которое добавляю в консоли wordpress - нет(((

***UPD*** В админке Wordpress, на странице виджетов, появился блок виджетов "sidebar-devhelper", но когда я туда что-либо добавляю, то вообще ничего не выводится!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы его вывести, нужно сначала его зарегистрировать в файле function.php Вашей темы.

Например:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Left Sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
}
```

А потом уже в теме его вызвать:

```
if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Left Sidebar') ) : ?>
        /* СЮДА все то, что должно выводиться если сайдбар не существует */
<?php endif; ?>
```

Посмотрите раздел wordpress сайта [phpdesigner.in.ua](http://phpdesigner.in.ua), может что нибудь пригодиться